# Cant seem to connect to Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Good day to any that bother to read and possibly respond to this query. I am currently trying to begin my small project that involves the use of Firebase. Being my first time using firebase I guided myself mostly by the tutorials that I was able to gather from youtube and the instructions given out by Firebase when they ask you in creating a new project. I feel I am stuck in this part of the instructions.

`<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->`
`<script src="/__/firebase/7.13.2/firebase-app.js"></script>`

`<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use`
 `https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->`
`<script src="/__/firebase/7.13.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>`

`<!-- Initialize Firebase -->`
`<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>`

It says to add it to the bottom of the  tag. Did so, then tried to add some stuff to the db by following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lEU1UEw3YI&t=726s
But alast I get nothing.

I am quite last, I have asked a couple of my clastmates and they say they either havent tried Firebase yet or their project doesnt require Cloud Base storage.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code below, is when you use `Firebase Hosting`

```
<script src="/__/firebase/7.14.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

if you are on your own server / localhost use

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

See this
[Add Firebase SDKs and initialize Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIqPWnveng6AIVhRWPCh18CQdXEAAYASABEgJvF_D_BwE#add-sdks-initialize) on `From Hosting URLs` tab and `From the CDN` tab

Comment: Thanks Ill try it